# How to resolve problem with chain select Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript

could you guys help me with that? i've trying to write a script with 2 level chain select but i have a error like this:

> scripts.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of
> undefined

have you any ideas why? error shows in console.log at last fucntion and looks like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> at cmo (scripts.js:76)
> at setTown (scripts.js:66)
> at scripts.js:61 cmo @ scripts.js:76 setTown @ scripts.js:66 (anonymous) @ scripts.js:61

Here's my code

```js
var json = {
"region":{
        "Warmińsko - mazurskie":{
            "town":{
            "Olsztyn":["Mercury", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
            "Elbląg": ["Mercury", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Radisson Blue", "Gołębiewski"],
            "Iława":["Mer", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
            "Ostróda":["Mercury", "Novotel","Mariot", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
            "Giżycko":["Mercury", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Vienna House", "Gołębiewski"],
            }
        },
        "Małopolskie":{
            "town":{
            "Kraków":["Kossak", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Radisson", "Stary"],
            "Tarnów":["Mercury", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Tarnovia", "Ibis"],
            "Oświęcim":["Mercure", "Golden Tulip","Sheraton", "Radisson", "Hampton"],
            "Skała":["Focus", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Radisson", "Zamek"],
            "Wieliczka":["Mercurius", "Novotel","Sheraton", "Arche", "Blue Star"],
        }
    },
    "Podlaskie":{
        "town":{
            "Białystok":["Altus", "Deo","Sheraton", "Radisson Blu", "Aquarion"],
            "Suwałki":["Merr", "Novotel","Ibis", "Radisson Red", "Arche"],
            "Łomża":["Mercury 2", "Telios","Sheraton", "Blue", "DeSilva"],
            "Augustów":["Mariot", "Unicus","Hampton", "Ibis Budget", "Ibis Styles"],
            "Zambrów":["Golden", "Blue Star","Sheraton", "Osteria", "Rafles"],
        }
    },
       "Podkarpackie":{
        "town":{
            "Rzeszów":["Blue Star", "Notel","Radius", "Puławski", "Grębiewski"],
            "Jasło":["Mercury2", "Novotel2","Sheraton2", "Radisson2", "Gołębiewski2"],
            "Krosno":["Mercury3", "Novotel3","Sheraton3", "Radisson3", "Gołębiewski3"],
            "Ustrzyki Górne":["Mercury4", "Novotel4","Sheraton4", "Radisson4", "Gołębiewski"],
            "Sanok":["Mercury5", "Novotel5","Sheraton5", "Radisson5", "Gołębiewski5"],
        }
    },
       "Mazowieckie":{
        "town":{
            "Warszawa":["Mercury6", "Novotel6","Sheraton6", "Radisson6", "Gołębiewski6"],
            "Sochaczew":["Mercury7", "Novotel7","Sheraton7", "Radisson7", "Gołębiewski7"],
            "Płock":["Mercury8", "Novotel8","Sheraton8", "Radisson8", "Gołębiewski8"],
            "Radom":["Mercury9", "Novotel9","Sheraton9", "Radisson9", "Gołębiewski9"],
            "Ciechanów":["Mercury0", "Novotel0","Sheraton0", "Radisson0", "Gołębiewski0"],
        }
    }
    }
}

var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));

console.log(typeof jsonData);

 var region = document.getElementById("region");
 var town = document.getElementById("town");
 var hotel = document.getElementById("hotel");

let reg = Object.keys(jsonData);
cmo(reg, region);
setTown();

function setTown(){
    town.innerHTML = "";
    let towns = jsonData[region.value];
    cmo(towns, town);
    setHotel();
};

function setHotel(){
    hotel.innerHTML = "";
    let hotels = jsonData[region.value][town.value];
    cmo(hotels, hotel);
};
function cmo(arr, s){
    arr.forEach(o => {
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = o;
        opt.innerHTML = o;
        s.add(opt);

    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Generowanie - wybór danych</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><label for = "region">Choose a region:</label>
<select name = "region" id = "region" onchange="setTown();">
    <option disabled selected value="">Select a region</option>
    <option value = "Warmińsko - mazurskie">Warmińsko - mazurskie</option>
    <option value = "Małopolskie">Małopolskie</option>
    <option value = "Podlaskie">Podlaskie</option>
    <option value = "Podkarpackie">Podkarpackie</option>
    <option value = "Mazowieckie">Mazowieckie</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label  for = "town">Choose a town:</label>
<select name = "town" id="town" onchange="setHotel();">
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="hotel" id="hotel">Choose a hotel:</label>
<select name="hotel" id="hotel">
</select>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start with this, even though it's unrelated to your question:

`var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));`

This is unnecessary. Your variable `json` is an object, not actual JSON.  This line converts it into JSON (with `stringify`) then back into an object identical to the one you started with (with `parse`).  You could skip all this and just use `json` directly (ideally with a less misleading name.)

Now on to your question:

There are a lot of problems here, most of them boiling down to "you're passing null to `cmo` where it expects an array.":

- You try to run the functions on load, when nothing is selected, which passes null to `cmo`
- Emptying the town `<select>` also fires its onChange event, passing its null value to `setHotel` and then `cmo`
- You had extra keys named "region" and "town" in your data, which you didn't account for when trying to match against that data
- You had a duplicate ID in your HTML, so when you were trying to check the value of the hotel select, you instead got the (nonexistent) value of its `label`
- ...and you had objects in your data you were accidentally trying to access as arrays.

Below is a corrected version; I've added comments where I made changes to your code:

```js
// renamed this, and removed the unneeded stringify-and-parse dance
var jsonData = {
  "region": {
    "Warmińsko - mazurskie": {
      "town": {
        "Olsztyn": ["Mercury", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
        "Elbląg": ["Mercury", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Radisson Blue", "Gołębiewski"],
        "Iława": ["Mer", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
        "Ostróda": ["Mercury", "Novotel", "Mariot", "Radisson", "Gołębiewski"],
        "Giżycko": ["Mercury", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Vienna House", "Gołębiewski"],
      }
    },
    "Małopolskie": {
      "town": {
        "Kraków": ["Kossak", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Radisson", "Stary"],
        "Tarnów": ["Mercury", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Tarnovia", "Ibis"],
        "Oświęcim": ["Mercure", "Golden Tulip", "Sheraton", "Radisson", "Hampton"],
        "Skała": ["Focus", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Radisson", "Zamek"],
        "Wieliczka": ["Mercurius", "Novotel", "Sheraton", "Arche", "Blue Star"],
      }
    },
    "Podlaskie": {
      "town": {
        "Białystok": ["Altus", "Deo", "Sheraton", "Radisson Blu", "Aquarion"],
        "Suwałki": ["Merr", "Novotel", "Ibis", "Radisson Red", "Arche"],
        "Łomża": ["Mercury 2", "Telios", "Sheraton", "Blue", "DeSilva"],
        "Augustów": ["Mariot", "Unicus", "Hampton", "Ibis Budget", "Ibis Styles"],
        "Zambrów": ["Golden", "Blue Star", "Sheraton", "Osteria", "Rafles"],
      }
    },
    "Podkarpackie": {
      "town": {
        "Rzeszów": ["Blue Star", "Notel", "Radius", "Puławski", "Grębiewski"],
        "Jasło": ["Mercury2", "Novotel2", "Sheraton2", "Radisson2", "Gołębiewski2"],
        "Krosno": ["Mercury3", "Novotel3", "Sheraton3", "Radisson3", "Gołębiewski3"],
        "Ustrzyki Górne": ["Mercury4", "Novotel4", "Sheraton4", "Radisson4", "Gołębiewski"],
        "Sanok": ["Mercury5", "Novotel5", "Sheraton5", "Radisson5", "Gołębiewski5"],
      }
    },
    "Mazowieckie": {
      "town": {
        "Warszawa": ["Mercury6", "Novotel6", "Sheraton6", "Radisson6", "Gołębiewski6"],
        "Sochaczew": ["Mercury7", "Novotel7", "Sheraton7", "Radisson7", "Gołębiewski7"],
        "Płock": ["Mercury8", "Novotel8", "Sheraton8", "Radisson8", "Gołębiewski8"],
        "Radom": ["Mercury9", "Novotel9", "Sheraton9", "Radisson9", "Gołębiewski9"],
        "Ciechanów": ["Mercury0", "Novotel0", "Sheraton0", "Radisson0", "Gołębiewski0"],
      }
    }
  }
}

var region = document.getElementById("region");
var town = document.getElementById("town");
var hotel = document.getElementById("hotel");

// removed attempts to init while selects are all empty

function setTown() {
  town.innerHTML = "";
  // corrected this line:
  let towns = Object.keys(jsonData.region[region.value].town);
  cmo(towns, town);
  setHotel();
};

function setHotel() {
  hotel.innerHTML = "";
  // corrected this line:
  let hotels = jsonData.region[region.value].town[town.value];
  cmo(hotels, hotel);
};

function cmo(arr, s) {
  if (arr.length) { // added this for safety: check if it's an array before you try to iterate over it
    arr.forEach(o => {
      let opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = o;
      opt.innerHTML = o;
      s.add(opt);

    });
  }
}
```

```html
<p><label for="region">Choose a region:</label>
  <select name="region" id="region" onchange="setTown();">
    <option disabled selected value="">Select a region</option>
    <option value="Warmińsko - mazurskie">Warmińsko - mazurskie</option>
    <option value="Małopolskie">Małopolskie</option>
    <option value="Podlaskie">Podlaskie</option>
    <option value="Podkarpackie">Podkarpackie</option>
    <option value="Mazowieckie">Mazowieckie</option>
  </select>
</p>

<p>
  <label for="town">Choose a town:</label>
  <select name="town" id="town" onchange="setHotel();">
  </select>
</p>

<p>
  <!-- changed this ID to not be a duplicate: -->
  <label for="hotel" id="hotelLabel">Choose a hotel:</label>
  <select name="hotel" id="hotel">
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Regarding your observation, JS devs use lines like `var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));` to create a deep copy of an object, I bet that is what the line does. Do you consider this right? I use it a lot too.

Comment: @xodeeq you may be right that that was the original intent of that line. It works, as long as there aren't circular references or functions in the data, but it's always felt like a bit of a hack to me to translate an object into a string and back again just to make a copy; I prefer `jsonData = Object.assign({},json)` or the more modern `jsonData = {...json}`.